# Core Data - NSManagedObject returning nil

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, swift2

I wrote two seperate functions `fetchRecords` and `displayRecords` written in `Appdelegate` Class. `fetchRecords` function will fetch all records from the entity and it is working fine.`displayRecords` function accepts the return value from `fetchRecords` function and prints all the records one by one. 
I have one view controller which calls these two functions to do the desired task. My problem is `result.count` in `displayRecords` shows the total number of records available in fetched records.While printing the records one by one the value is nil.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    let fetchedRecords = AppDelegate().fetchRecords(fromEntity: "Dashboard")
    AppDelegate().displayRecords(fromFetchedRecords: fetchedRecords)   
}
```

And here is the `fetchRecords` and `displayRecords` functions written in AppDelegate Class

```
  func fetchRecords(fromEntity entity:String) -> Array<AnyObject> {
    var fetchedResult:Array<AnyObject> = []
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entity, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)!
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
    do{
        fetchedResult = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)              
    }catch{
        let fetchError = error as NSError?
        print(fetchError!)
    }
   return fetchedResult
}

func displayRecords(fromFetchedRecords result:Array<AnyObject>) {
    print("Total records:\(result.count)")
    if (result.count > 0) {
        for data in result {
        let dashboard = data as! NSManagedObject
        print("Value: \(dashboard.valueForKey("count"))")
        }
    }
}
```

Adding my data model here
[image]

I will share the data insertion code also.

```
func saveDashBoardData(dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask))

    //Create Manage Object
    let entityDescription: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Dashboard", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)!
    for data in dictionary {
        let dashboardObject = Dashboard(entity: entityDescription,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        dashboardObject.type  = data.0
        dashboardObject.count = data.1
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            print("Data saved succesfully")
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your coredata model in your project @sindhu ja

Comment: I have shared the data model in the question. Please find it

Comment: I couldn't get what you trying to say @vadian

Comment: @sindhu ja : can you put a break point at let dashboard = data as! NSManagedObject and confirm if dashboard object is nil ?? I guess it wont be if it was nil it would have crashed at that point itself. That means your fetch request is fecthing dashboard object properly, but may be dashboard object has no value for property in count :) So what you can do is post your code for inserting dashboard objects into coredata

Comment: @SandeepBhandari The insertion is working fine and I can see the data in DB. Anyhow I will share the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `AppDelegate()` creates always a new instance of the class which is not the same as the "hard-coded" delegate instance of the application.

You have to write

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let fetchedRecords = appDelegate.fetchRecords(fromEntity: "Dashboard")
appDelegate.displayRecords(fromFetchedRecords: fetchedRecords)
```

Since you have created a custom subclass of `NSManagedObject` use it as type rather than `NSManagedObject` or – worse – the unspecified `AnyObject`. It makes many things much easier:

```
func fetchRecords(fromEntity entity:String) -> [Dashboard] {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
  let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entity, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)!
  fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
  do {
     return try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Dashboard]              
  } catch let fetchError as NSError {
     print(fetchError!)
  }
  return [Dashboard]()
}

func displayRecords(fromFetchedRecords result:[Dashboard]) {
    print("Total records:\(result.count)")

    for dashboard in result { // the check for empty is not needed
       print("Value: \(dashboard.count)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian. Creating the instance for `AppDelegate` solves the problem.

Comment: Using tight coupling to the AppDelegate is bad and will cause you more hassles than it is worth.  You are far better off following the design laid out recently in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) rather than what is in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
let dashboard = Dashboard as! NSManagedObject

print("Value: \(dashboard.count)")
```

I think it might work. Because you have taken your ManagedObject as **data**. Better you take it as kind of **Dashboard**. So that you can access **count** by dashboardObj.count ..

Hope you created Core Data NSManagedSubclass for the Entity.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Yes I already created NSManagedSubclass for that entity. I tried your suggestion but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSManagedObject subclass of Dashboard from your coredata model.

```
func displayRecords(fromFetchedRecords result:Array<AnyObject>) {

    print("Total records:\(result.count)")
    if (result.count > 0) {
        for data in result {
        let dashboard = data as! Dashboard
        print("Value: \(dashboard.valueForKey("count"))")
        }
    }
}
```

Key change here is   let dashboard = data as! Dashboard.
Dashboard is managed object subclass which you need to create with core data model help.

Comment: Thanks @Dovakin. We used your suggestion and creating the instance for `AppDelegate` solved the issue.